# ADAL JS not attaching user token while invoking WebApi

Tags: javascript, azure, asp.net-web-api, adal.js

I am using `ADAL JS` for authenticating the users against Azure AD. And as I am new to `ADAL JS`, I started reading with following articles, which I find very informative:

- [Introducing ADAL JS v1](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/introducing-adal-js-v1/)
- [ADAL JavaScript and AngularJS – Deep Dive](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/)

After reading the articles, I had the impression that `ADAL JS` intercepts the service calls and if the service url is registered as one of the endpoint in `AuthenticationContext` configuration, it attaches the JWT token as Authentication Bearer information.

However, I found the same is not happening in my case. And after some digging, it seemed to me that it is only possible, if `adal-angular` counter part is also used, which I am not using currently, simply because my web application is not based on Angular.

Please let me know if my understanding is correct or not. If I need to add the bearer information explicitly, the same can be done, but I am more concerned whether I am missing some out-of-the-box facility or not.

**Additional Details:** My present configuration looks like following:

```
private endpoints: any = {
    "https://myhost/api": "here_goes_client_id"
}
...
private config: any;
private authContext: any = undefined;
....
this.config = {
    tenant: "my_tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
    clientId: "client_id_of_app_in_tenant_ad",
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
    endpoints: this.endpoints
};
this.authContext = new (window["AuthenticationContext"])(this.config);
```

Also on server-side (WebApi), Authentication configuration (Startup.Auth) is as follows:

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app, HttpConfiguration httpConfig)
{
    app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Tenant = "my_tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidAudience = "client_id_of_app_in_tenant_ad"
            }
         });
}
```

However, the `Authorization` is always null in `request.Headers`.

**UPDATE:** It seems that the same applies for auto-renewal of tokens as well; when used in conjunction with `adal-angular`, the renewal of token works seamlessly by calling `AuthenticationContext.acquireToken(resource, callback)` under the hood. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> After reading the articles, I had the impression that ADAL JS intercepts the service calls and if the service url is registered as one of the endpoint in AuthenticationContext configuration, it attaches the JWT token as Authentication Bearer information.

This will work only if your application is angular based. As you mentioned, the logic for this lives in adal-angular.

If, however, you want to stick to pure JS, you will not get the automatic "get-access-token-and-attach-it-to-header" support. You can use `acquireToken(resource, callback` api to get a token for the endpoint. But you will have to do some work in the controller that is sending the request to the api.

This might give you some idea: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/blob/master/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/Ctrls/todoListCtrl.js. This sample does not uses angular.

Answer (score 0):

ADAL.JS is incompatible with v2.0 implicit flow. I could not get it working since I set my project up recently and don't think projects are backwards compatible.

This was very confusing and took me a long time to figure out that I was mixing up the versions, and can't use ADAL.JS with v2.0. Once I removed it, things went much smoother, just did a couple of XHR requests and a popup window, no magic actually required!

Here is code for v2:

```
function testNoADAL() {
    var clientId = "..guid..";
    var redirectUrl = "..your one.."
    var authServer = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?";
    var responseType = "token";
    var stateParam = Math.random() * new Date().getTime();

    var authUrl = authServer +
                                "response_type=" + encodeURI(responseType) +
                                "&client_id=" + encodeURI(clientId) +
                                "&scope=" + encodeURI("https://outlook.office.com/Mail.ReadWrite") +
                                "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURI(redirectUrl) +
                                "&state=" + stateParam;

    var popupWindow = window.open(authUrl, "Login", 'width=' + 300 + ', height=' + 600 + ', top=' + 10 + ', left=' + 10 + ',location=no,toolbar=yes');
    if (popupWindow.focus) {
        popupWindow.focus();
    }
}
```

Note: redirectUrl will appear in popup window, needs to have code in it to pass location hash, such as this:

`<script>window.opener.processMicrosoftAuthResultUrl(location.hash);window.close();</script>`

```
function processMicrosoftAuthResultUrl(hash) {
    if (hash.indexOf("#") == 0) {
        hash = hash.substr(1);
    }
    var obj = getUrlParameters(hash);
    if (obj.error) {
        if (obj.error == "invalid_resource") {
            errorDialog("Your Office 365 needs to be configured to enable access to Outlook Mail.");
        } else {
            errorDialog("ADAL: " + obj.error_description);
        }
    } else {
        if (obj.access_token) {
            console.log("ADAL got access token!");
            var token = obj.access_token;
            var url = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/Inbox/messages";
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                },
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log("got data!", data);
                var message = "Your latest email is: " + data.value[0].Subject + " from " + data.value[0].From.EmailAddress.Name+ " on " + df_FmtDateTime(new Date(data.value[0].ReceivedDateTime));
                alertDialog(message);

            }).fail(function () {
                console.error('Error getting todo list data')
            });
        }
    }
}

function getUrlParameters(url) {
    // get querystring and turn it into an object
    if (!url) return {};
    if (url.indexOf("?") > -1) {
        url = url.split("?")[1];
    }
    if (url.indexOf("#") > -1) {
        url = url.split("#")[0];
    }
    if (!url) return {};
    url = url.split('&')
    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < url.length; ++i) {
        var p = url[i].split('=', 2);
        if (p.length == 1) {
            b[p[0]] = "";
        } else {
            b[decodeURIComponent(p[0])] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: This is extremely interesting to me. I also don't use angular, but was able to deploy and use the aforementioned [sample ADAL.js non-angular app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/) - but, it's only drawback was that the SPA and WebAPI are on the same app registration. I cannot get things to work for my CORS-enabled Web API when my ADAL.js is on a different domain and different app registration.

Comment: Get rid of ADAL.js, it is legacy code, no longer supported and not needed