# My RBAC'd Web API is secure, but, the roles aren't working

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory, rbac, adal.js

I have a simple ADAL.js 'spa' app [based on this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi). It is calling an API that is part of the same solution (so, I don't think this is a CORS issue, we're all in the same domain here.. same app)

I set up some custom roles in my AD tenant's app's manifest file. I associated those roles with some test user accounts. When I run my sample and login, it reflects back to me user token values that show that the correct role has been applied to whatever test user I decided to login with...

When I make calls to the API where we've just simply used the `[Authorize]` attribute, everything is fine.

For example, this decorated controller, works fine:

```
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get(){...omitted....}
}
```

However, this gives me a 'denied' response (literally: `Authorization has been denied for this request`):

```
[Authorize(Roles = "AdminAccess")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()(){...omitted....}
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Seems to fail when deployed to Azure, as well as locally

---

Here's my `Startup.Auth.cs` class:

```
    public partial class Startup
    {
      public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {

        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                },
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],

            });
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Have you set the `RoleClaimType` in authentication setup? You have to tell the component validating the JWT which claim contains roles.

Comment: @juunas - thanks for the tip, I updated my question to show my `Startup.Auth.cs` class. Are you talking about something akin to [this](http://ronaldwildenberg.com/combining-adal-js-with-role-based-security-in-asp-net-web-api/)?

Comment: That one gets user's group memberships when they call the API. What you want is to read the roles from the JSON Web Token passed to your API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define which claim contains the roles. Here is an example:

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        Tenant = Tenant,
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience = ValidAudience,
            RoleClaimType = "roles"
        }
    });
```

This causes the middleware to map values in the claim "roles" to roles for the principal it creates.

Comment: I've heard that "[ADAL.JS is incompatible with v2.0 implicit flow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44227814)" - even though I was able to successfully deploy the sample ADAL.JS app referred to in my O.P. - I am having issues now that I'm wanting to split my sample into a separate, CORS-enabled Web API, with a dedicated AD registration for my SPA. Any thoughts?  My bearer token JWT is missing a 'roles' claim in it.

Comment: If the roles are still defined on your front end app, they won't be included in access tokens for the API. You would need to define the roles on the API's manifest and assign them to users.

Comment: Double checked my SPA registration's manifest, `appRoles:[]` is good and empty. Double-checked that my app.js uses the SPA's `ClientID` correctly. Have checked to ensure I've granted API access to the new SPA registration